# File is not under version control when commiting from jenkins to SVN after sccessful build

Tags: svn, jenkins, maven-3

Building a Maven (Java) project with Jenkins, I would like to commit my pom.xml when the build process ends (the pom changes during the build).

To do that I used the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb0l4.png) (of Jenkins) and triggered the following shell command:

```
svn commit -m "Committing pom with newly Autoincremented version" _WORKSPACE/_pox.xml
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

The commit fails with this message:

```
Run condition [Current build status] enabling perform for step [Execute shell]
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2955093422560733923.sh
+ svn commit -m Committing pom with newly Autoincremented version pox.xml
svn: E200009: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200009: '/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins-data/jobs/RTB/workspace/pox.xml' is not under version control
Build step 'Conditional step (single)' marked build as failure

  [1]: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8srY.png
```

I navigated to this path in my Jenkins server (/var/lib/jenkins/jenkins-data/jobs/RTB/workspace/) and triggered a commit from there (using command line) and it worked. I really don't understand why can't it be done from Jenkins.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you do a `which svn` in the jenkins step and also from the shell where it works. Are you logged in as the jenkins user when it works too?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - what do you mean when you say "which svn"? is it a jenkins command or something like that?

Comment: you can add it as line in your Builder step above as it a shell command to give you the path to the executable. In this case, the svn you are running. You can also become the jenkins user with `su - jenkins` once you have logged in as root on the Jenkins server

Comment: ill give it a shot and let you know. tnx

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn as I'm adding + which svn I'm getting this output: + which svn
/usr/bin/svn.  As I'm addingn the su - jenkins command I get su: must be run from a terminal. In both cases my pom does not get committed to svn.

Comment: I was thinking you could login as the jenkins user in a terminal and try to run the svn commit from there

Comment: Did it already, it worked, this is why I'm surprised I'm failing doing the same from the build job :(

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows `_WORKSPACE/_pom.xml` yet your error shows `workspace/pom.xml`. That doesn't match up.